# Socket.IO / node.js problem: unintended disconnects

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I see this sort of thing in my node log fairly frequently:

19 Feb 13:50:20 - Initializing client with transport "flashsocket"

19 Feb 13:50:20 - Client 5846663371194154 connected

19 Feb 13:50:20 - Client 5846663371194154 disconnected

It seems to happen more often with with the flashsocket but I can't be certain about that.

Has anyone else experienced this?

EDIT: I should also add: the connect and disconnect events are not firing on the client side. So I'm not sure how I could know when this has occured.

Comment: I find it strange that you aren't getting any events on the client. You might want to investigate that more, or post another question on here if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I've done more work on this.

The problem is easily reproducible if you set the connectTimeout for the socket object to a very low number. Say 100 ms.

The solution is to increase the timeout or to retry connections after a connection failure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will happen. To be reliable your code has to be able to sensibly handle clients reconnecting.